# How to submit html form in web browser control, by submitting winform?

Tags: c#

I want to submit an html form inside a web browser control, upon submitting parent winform. (scenario: a web api sends a response when html form is submitted. this html form is contained in a winform. end user only gets to see winform dialog's submit button.)

Parent form submit button functionality is as follows:

```
btnYes.Click += (s, ea) => {
            // Set property value
            CardType = cmbCCType.SelectedItem.ToString();
            CardHolderName = txtCardHolderName.Text;
            CompnyName = txtCompanyName.Text;
            Street = txtStreet.Text;
            City = txtCity.Text;
            County = txtCounty.Text;
            State = txtState.Text;
            Zip = txtZip.Text;
            CountryRegion = cmbRegion.SelectedValue.ToString();
            Telephone = txtTelephone.Text;
            Email = txtEmail.Text;
            CardNotes = txtCCNote.Text;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) && !regEMail.IsMatch(Email))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Enter valid email address", "Invalid EMail Address");
                ((Form)((Control)s).Parent).DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
                return;
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Telephone) && !regPhone.IsMatch(Telephone))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Only # / ' - _ . , and space characters are allowed", "Invalid Phone Number");
                ((Form)((Control)s).Parent).DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                ((Form)((Control)s).Parent).DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
                ((Form)((Control)s).Parent).Close();
            }
        };
```

Code to get response from html form is:

```
HtmlElement hdnIsError = firstDataTokenPanel.Document.GetElementById("hdnIsError");
HtmlElement hdnResponse = firstDataTokenPanel.Document.GetElementById("hdnResponse");
String payeezyJSResponse = hdnResponse.GetAttribute("value");
```

I have to use dual submission on a single button. I emphasize on this point as html form is only available when winform.showDialog(). So any attempt to submit html form through invokeMember etc. before or after dialog is futile, as html form is only available till winform dialog is shown.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't "submit" a winforms form

Comment: Pardon my lack of knowledge, I am relatively new to c#. The form I am referring to is System.Windows.Forms.Form

Comment: I know, you can't submit that (it won't post etc.) you can however click a button. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. I have a custom button, which will be clicked. On that click event, the aforementioned functionality needs to be achieved.

Comment: I'm not sure what you have now and what you want to achieve. (hard to paint a picture) Do you just need to automatically submit a form(http) on a button click(winforms)?

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly.

Comment: Can't you get the element like in your example and post (the element/form)  right before you close your winform? I'm a little fuzzy on web stuff in winforms